# Variable in string

Tags: php, string, variables

I know that we can use variable inside a string.
For example:

```
<?php
    $name = "pink panther";
    $message = "Hello, Im $name"; // 1
    $other_message = "Hello, Im {$name}"; // 2
?>
```

Both of $message and $other_message are ok. It's so common.
However, i see another syntax for this problem.

```
$third_way = "Hello, Im ${name}"; // 3
```

The 3rd way still ok (im using php version 7). I like this syntax because it is like javascript template . But i have never seen who use that way.
So any problem when i use this syntax?
Thank for your comment!

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what the actual question is here

Comment: i prefer the 3rd syntax to others, but i did see that on php.net or somewhere else.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `"{$var}"` thing is called complex syntax in PHP's double quote strings because with it you can for instance access multidimensional array values on objects with both numeric and string indexes and optionally use even single quotes to access the index. Example:

```
$result = "{$var->val[3]->arr['idx'][3]}";
```

`"${var}"` on the other side would fall into the category of simple syntax and is (in my opinion) primarily useful for cases like this:

```
$result = "${var}s";
```

I wouldn't generally apply curly braces for three reasons:

- I find it easier to read `"hi $name"` than `"hi ${name}"`
- They are less common
- They are not necessary, so when I read that code I would ask myself for a couple of milliseconds: "why did he put curly braces?"

But the decision is up to you or to your team. Find more about it in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: makes no sense to use `${name}` vs `$name` here

Comment: @IdontDownVote Well most examples out there prefer `$name` over `${name}`. The answer to 'why is `${name}` so rarely used?': Because the `$name` syntax exists.